# Problem with Oracle (Spatial Geometry) query

Tags: sql, oracle, spatial

I'm trying to form a query that returns a list of entities within a given rectangle, using SDO_WITHIN_DISTANCE. The query I've made seems like it should work, but Oracle is giving me some strange errors. Here's the query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TBLENTITYLOCATION TL
      INNER JOIN TBLENTITY TE 
      ON TE.ENTITYID=TL.ENTITYID  
WHERE SDO_WITHIN_DISTANCE (TL.GEOLOCATION
                           , SDO_GEOMETRY (2003
                                         , NULL
                                         , NULL
                                         , SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 1003, 3)
                                         , SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(41, -73, 36, -82)
                              ), 'DISTANCE=10 UNIT=M'
                          ) = 'TRUE' 
AND  TL.LOCATIONDATETIME= (select MAX(LOCATIONDATETIME) 
                           FROM TBLENTITYLOCATION 
                           WHERE  ENTITYID = TE.ENTITYID)
```

**The error is as follows:**

```
ORA-29902: error in executing ODCIIndexStart() routine
ORA-13208: internal error while evaluating [window SRID does not match layer SRID] operator
ORA-06512: at MDSYS.SDO_INDEX_METHOD_10I", line 286
```

OERR says:

```
29902. 00000 -  "error in executing ODCIIndexStart() routine"
*Cause:    The execution of ODCIIndexStart routine caused an error.
*Action:   Examine the error messages produced by the indextype code and take appropriate action.
```

Thanks for any help or ideas.

Comment: Which version of Oracle database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ORA-13208 error is the prime one here.
The TL.GEOLOCATION needs a matching value in the SRID (second parameter of the SDO_GEOMETRY)

See if the response [here](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=218341#602492) helps you out.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response - Thank you for this reply - that was the correct error!

Answer (score 1):

Gary Myers provided correct answer, let me augment it. If you don't know which SRID is used by your table, do a query:

```
select SRID from USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA where TABLE_NAME='TBLENTITYLOCATION' and COLUMN_NAME='TBLENTITYLOCATION'
```

Also, to query for objects which are within a rectangle, you don't need SDO_WITHIN_DISTANCE operator. Instead, use SDO_RELATE with mask=ANYINTERACT. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10826/sdo_operat.htm#i78531 for more details.