# Oracle Spatial: I can't get sdo_inside to work

Tags: oracle, geospatial, oracle-spatial

I'm trying to build a map tile server for Oracle Spatial Database. I need to filter the query with bounding boxes so that I can get individual tile data.

I convert the bounding box data into WKT and I'm trying to use SDO_UTILS.FROM_WKTGEOMETRY with SDO_INSIDE so that I can get tile data. Here is my resulting query:

```
select SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(SDO_UTIL.SIMPLIFY(sdo_cs.transform(SHAPE, sdo_cs.map_epsg_srid_to_oracle(4326)), 6, 0.000001)) as GEOM,
column_1,
column_2,
column_3
from tablename 
where SDO_INSIDE(SHAPE, SDO_UTIL.FROM_WKTGEOMETRY(TO_CHAR('POLYGON ((28.125 40.979898069620155, 30.9375 40.979898069620155, 30.9375 43.068887774169625, 28.125 43.068887774169625, 28.125 40.979898069620155))'))) = 'TRUE'
```

This query says:

```
ORA-29902: Runtime error on ODCIIndexStart()
ORA-13208: [window SRID does not match layer SRID]
ORA-06512: location "MDSYS.SDO_INDEX_METHOD_10I", line 333
```

Then I tried sdo_cs.transform on both the column SHAPE and sdo_util.from_wktgeometry geometries in the same way as the first line of the query and it receives another error.

EDIT: I checked out the question that might contain the answer, I applied the transform and what I got is:

```
ORA-13226: interface not supported without a spatial index
ORA-06512: location "MDSYS.MD",  line 1723
ORA-06512: location "MDSYS.MDERR",  line 8
ORA-06512: location "MDSYS.SDO_3GL",  line 88
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem with Oracle (Spatial Geometry) query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259226/problem-with-oracle-spatial-geometry-query)

Comment: Didn't work, my problem deviates from that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did:

```
SDO_INSIDE(SDO_UTIL.FROM_WKTGEOMETRY(SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(SHAPE)), SDO_UTIL.FROM_WKTGEOMETRY('INSERT LARGE WKT TEXT HERE'))
```

And everything started working.

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues with your example.

The first error ("window SRID does not match layer SRID") happens because the geometries in your table are properly encoded with a coordinate system identifier (SRID) but your query window does not have one. This means that the query system has no way to correlate the coordinates you pass with those of the data you query. Note that the SRID of the query window does not have to be the same as that of the table being queried.

Then you do not need to explicitly transform from WKT: the SDO_GEOMETRY constructor does that automatically. Just pass it the WKT string along with the SRID of the query window, like this:

```
SDO_GEOMETRY('POLYGON ((28.125 40.979898069620155, 30.9375 40.979898069620155, 30.9375 43.068887774169625, 28.125 43.068887774169625, 28.125 40.979898069620155))',4326)
```

The second error ("interface not supported without a spatial index") is because the first argument to SDO_INSIDE is not spatially indexed. A spatial index is required if you want to perform any kind of spatial query.

You transform the shapes returned by the query to WGS84 using this:

```
sdo_cs.transform(SHAPE, sdo_cs.map_epsg_srid_to_oracle(4326))
```

That is only needed iff the data in your SHAPE column is in another coordinate system than WGS84. And why do you need the `map_epsg_srid_to_oracle(4326)` call ?

Finally, you said that this works:

```
SDO_INSIDE(SDO_UTIL.FROM_WKTGEOMETRY(SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(SHAPE)), SDO_UTIL.FROM_WKTGEOMETRY('INSERT LARGE WKT TEXT HERE'))
```

That is just impossible - unless you defined a spatial index on the first expression `SDO_UTIL.FROM_WKTGEOMETRY(SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(SHAPE))`. Is this what you did ? I don't see the point. All you need is a spatial index on the SHAPE column.

Considering the above, the following will work (don't forget to define an index on TABLENAME.SHAPE. If that table is already in WGS84, then the transformation is not needed either.

```
select SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(SDO_UTIL.SIMPLIFY(sdo_cs.transform(SHAPE,4326)),6, 0.000001)) as GEOM,
column_1,
column_2,
column_3
from tablename 
where SDO_INSIDE(SHAPE, SDO_GEOMETRY('POLYGON ((28.125 40.979898069620155, 30.9375 40.979898069620155, 30.9375 43.068887774169625, 28.125 43.068887774169625, 28.125 40.979898069620155))',4326)) = 'TRUE';
```

Comment: while this was not the quickest answer I got from stackoverflow, this was surely one of the most helpful. thank you so much sir.